# Find cached image with Signature Android glide

Tags: android, android-glide

im using this code because every time the image change on the server i want to download the latest.

```
 Glide.with(yourFragment)
 .load(yourFileDataModel)
 .signature(new StringSignature(new ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
 .into(yourImageView);
```

But there is a problem here. If internet connection goes out (or smt) glide cant find the image in disk cache and will show an error. How can i find the cached image using signature?

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong `key` for signature. `System.currentTimeMillis()` changes in each milli seconds. What you want to do is provide some key which will only change when the image changes. You'll have to do something like this. You can ask for `image.getUpdatedAt()` from the server.

```
GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(glideUrlCacheKey)
        .signature(new ObjectKey(image.getUpdatedAt()))
        .into(holder.customerImage);
```

Comment: So I need to request server for modified date before load image from the sever.Look troublesome...Btw, I think this answer at least explain why Glide always doesn't use cache. Here is +1.

Comment: @Yeung Glide automatically does caching and it should work as long as the URL is same or image data is not removed due to space limit. Using a signature key is a specific case where you want to have more control over caching. In our case, image URLs are always changing because they all are private and I still had to cache it, so we used a dummy URL and signature key to update cached images.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might helpful for you

```
Glide.with(mContext)
  .load(urlProfile)
  .apply(RequestOptions.signature(new StringSignature(...))
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
  .into(imageView);
```

Use the `signature` by applying `RequestOptions`

Useful link: http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions

Answer (score 1):

for offline work store the url of the image in sqllite and check if internet connection is not active give glide the url from sqllite